# Authorization Requirement Handler Using DI

Tags: asp.net-core, policy

I am trying to get a dependency injected into the constructor of a custom authorization handler, but the `AddAuthorization` in asp.net is making it difficult.

Handler:

```cs
class MyHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MyRequirement>
{
    readonly IDependent dependency;

    public UserExistsHandler(IDependent dependency)
    {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyRequirement requirement)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MyHandler>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(config =>
{
    config.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", policy =>
    {
        // how?
        policy.AddRequirements(new )
    });
});
```

According to official documentation this should be possible:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/dependencyinjection?view=aspnetcore-6.0

However, the signature for `AddRequirements` is not generic and requires me to pass an actual instance of the handler which I cannot do because I have no reference to the `IServiceProvider` in the config delegate.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/4faa84c9ddf8c9e9cc9e5b43ca15f090037c4b68/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/AuthorizationPolicyBuilder.cs#L73

How do I register the handler without having to create a new instance to be registered which defeats the purpose of the DI I am trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the handler that you need to pass to `AddRequirements`, but the an instance of `MyRequirement`.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(config =>
{
    config.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.AddRequirements(new MyRequirement());
    });
});
```